# insert still works after Meteor.logout

Tags: meteor

This Meteor app has the insecure and autopublish removed and accounts-password added.
It uses `Accounts.createUser({username: someName, password: somePwrd});`
It avoids using allow/deny and uses instead Meteor.call to insert documents because reading in the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow), it says that

> Server code is trusted and isn't subject to allow and deny restrictions. That includes methods that are called with Meteor.call — they are expected to do their own access checking rather than relying on allow and deny.

But when I fire up the `Meteor.logout()`, I am still able to insert new documents to Tasks1 collection. How can that be? I though logout will stop inserting any new documents. How can I fix it? Thanks

```
///////////////////////////
//both/both.js
///////////////////////////
Tasks1 = new Mongo.Collection('tasks1');

///////////////////////////
//server/server.js
///////////////////////////
Meteor.publish('tasks1', function(){
  return Tasks1.find({userId: this.userId});
});

Meteor.methods({
  addTasks1: function (doc) {
    Tasks1.insert(doc);
  }
});

///////////////////////////
//client/client.js
///////////////////////////
Template.footer.events({
  'click button': function () {
     if ( this.text === "SUBMIT" ) {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          var params = {};
          params[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;
          Meteor.call('addTasks1', params);
         }
      }
   }
 });

Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click #logout': function () {
    Meteor.logout();
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server `addTasks1` method, you should first check if the user is a user like so:

```
Meteor.methods({
    addTasks1: function(doc) {
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("Not Authorized");
        } else {
            Tasks1.insert(doc);
        }

    }
})
```

Logout alone doesn't stop users from being able to insert. You must edit your method code to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 addTasks1: function (doc) {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
        Tasks1.insert(doc);
    }
 }
```